# Keep google analytics tracking while using google tag manager

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have to set Google Tag Manager on a Magento website that already has google analytics tracking on it.
The main goal is to replace all the old tracking by Google tag Manager and Universal Analytics.

I would like to know the best way to achieve this goal.

Is it possible, in a first phase, to keep the existing google analytics tracking and to set up Google Tag Manager in the same time ? For example, I would like to be able to set remarketing campaigns in the tag manager.

Or do I have to delete all related google analytics code on the website and create new tags in the Google Tag Manager interface ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep them separate. Implementing Analytics via the tag manager might make your live easier in the long run, but they are completely separate products that do not depend on each other.